# Jump to spinner selection

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, spinner

I have a spinner (Actionbar Sherlock Widget) with 20-30 elements; the last one is selected.
After opening the spinner, i have to scroll down to the selection. Is there a way to open the spinner and to see the selection without scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionBarSherlock **4.3.0** was released today. This seems to be fixed in the new version according to the last line in in the [changelog](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md):

> Fix: Scroll list navigation to the selected item when opened.